# I have nested list object called episodes from JSON so how to get list of episodes based on id parent object not by position object?

Tags: json, flutter

This is API JSON so how can I get a list of episodes based on id item object not by position of object list

```
"results": [
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Wannous",
        "description": "After yaqout the father left his wife and kids and disappeared for 20 years, the Devil (Wannous) came to his family claiming that he's their father's friend telling them that their father and (Wannous) own millions",
        "portalId": "primax",
        "type": "series",
        "age": "70",
        "releaseDate": "2020-05-18 00:00:00",
        "viewsNum": 0,
        "cCover1": "images/series/20200518140210_HgQ2G.jpg",
        "cCover2": null,
        "cPoster1": "images/series/20200518140210_CmkOf.jpg",
        "cPoster2": null,
        "mCover1": "images/series/20200518140210_erBqc.jpg",
        "mCover2": null,
        "mPoster1": "images/series/20200518140210_tkNGp.jpg",
        "mPoster2": null,
        "createdAt": "2020-05-18 14:02:10",
        "updatedAt": null,
        "movie": null,
        "episodes": [
            {
                "id": 219,
                "title": "Wannous",
                "description": "After (Yaqout) the father left his wife and kids and disappeared for 20 years, the Devil (Wannous) came to his family claiming that he's their father's friend telling them that their father and (Wannous) own millions.",
                "image": null,
                "cover": "videos/2020_05_21/images/20200521193406_QkHD8.jpg",
                "video": "videos/2020_05_21/20200521193406_wGIDS.mp4",
                "promo": "videos/2020_05_21/20200521193406_vjQkW.jpg",
                "displayAt": "2020-05-20 21:00:00",
                "duration": "35:25",
                "viewsNum": 0,
                "position": 1,
                "avgWatchTime": 0.0,
                "likesNum": 0,
                "portalId": "primax",
                "createdAt": "2020-05-21 19:34:06",
                "updatedAt": "2020-05-23 12:21:19",
                "tags": []
            }
        ],
        "trailers": [],
        "portalReleased": true
    } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `json` is the result you got from the API.
the code below should return a `map` to you from the list based on the `ID` you pass to it.

```
Map getItemById(){
   List items = json['results'];
   Map itemById = items.where((item)=>item['id'] == 1).toList()[0];
   return itemById;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Quicktype.io to generate a class converter in dart to convert the json to an object/map. Pass this class to the Future you are using to retrieve the data from the Api. And now this data is received as an indexed snapshot list of results.  Using this index you can create a listview or retrieve items from any index.